# Help with converting integral to Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I have the integral
$$\int_1^3\sin(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
and I want to convert it to a Riemann Sum. I understand that the first thing I should do is set the limit as $n\to\infty$. I am stumped as what I should do next. Can someone walk me through the steps of converting integrals to Riemann Sums?

Comment: Perhaps review this and the examples: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-accumulation-riemann-sums/ab-defining-definite-integral/a/definite-integral-as-the-limit-of-a-riemann-sum

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I suppose you mean for the integral from $1$  to $3$?

Comment: @Bernard yes, I'm not quite familiar with mathematical formatting

Comment: Can you show us an attempt at least, so then we can help explain where you went wrong (or right)?

Comment: I started out by finding delta x, which should be (3-1)/n, and that is the width of each rectangle. Then, I need to find the height of each rectangle, but I don't know how to do that. I think it's something like adding on to the first x value on my interval, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @kydd It would be $f(a + \Delta x i)$ where $i$ is the index of summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to introduce the subdivision points. As the intercal is $[1,3]$, with length $2$, we obtain:
$$x_0=1,\:x_1=1+\frac2n,\dots,\: x_i=1+i\cdot \frac 2n,\dots,\: x_n=1+n\cdot \frac 2n=3$$

Then, the Riemann sums associated with this subdivision are
\begin{align}
s_n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sin x_i\,\cdot\frac2n=\frac2n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sin\Bigl(1+\frac{2i}n\Bigr),\\[1ex]
S_n&=\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin\Bigl(1+\frac{2i}n\Bigr).
\end{align}